# "bash: pybot command not found" on Red Hat Enterprise Linux server

Tags: robotframework

I successfully installed the following on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux system:

1) Python 2.7

http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel

2) Robot Framework

```
pip install robotframework
```

3) Selenium2Library
    pip install robotframework-selenium2library

But I get the command not found error,

```
pybot --version
bash: pybot: command not found
```

or

```
robot --version
bash: robot: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood that the "pip" command does not install the packages into the systems directory.
It rather installs them in /usr/local/bin/

You can fix the PATH variable on RHEL to make it work:
update the PATH as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
```

Now the commands will work as expected:

```
pybot --version
Robot Framework 3.0.1 (Python 2.7.12 on linux2)

robot --version
Robot Framework 3.0.1 (Python 2.7.12 on linux2)
```